# Patch over raster A with values from raster B where raster A values are nodata in GDAL

Tags: gdal, gdal-merge

I'm trying to come up with a way to patch over raster A with data from raster B. Extent of raster A can be smaller than raster B.

More specifically, I'd like to patch over nodata values from raster A with raster B values as well as create pixels in raster A where they exist in raster B.

Simple gdal_merge doesn't work for me as this doesn't work:

`gdal_merge -o out.tif rasterA.tif rasterB.tif`

as it is replacing values in raster A with values of raster B and would like values in raster A to be kept where they are not nodata.

and this won't work

`gdal_merge -o out.tif rasterB.tif rasterA.tif`

as it will replace values in raster B with nodata from raster A.

gdal_calc won't work, as rasters have different dimesions.

I'm aware that this such conditional logic can be [implemented in Arc](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/5251/6332), but I'm looking for a solution using GDAL. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formulating the question helped me answer it myself. To solve this, 3 steps are required:

Step 1: create a nodata mask equal in size to raster B (255 is the nodata value)

`gdal_calc -A rasterB.tif --outfile=mask.tif --calc="255"`

Step 2: merge over raster A over this mask

`gdal_merge -o rasterA_extended.tif mask.tif rasterA.tif`

Step 3: conditional gdal_calc, update only where nodata

`gdal_calc -A rasterA_extended.tif -B rasterB.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A*(A<255) + B*(A==255)"`

Additionally, if don't want to copy over value, but you need to set all pixels to be patched to a specific value (0 in my case), you can use this logic:

`gdal_calc -A rasterA_extended.tif -B rasterB.tif --outfile=!res.tif --calc="A*(A<255) + 0*(logical_and(A==255,B<>255)) + A*(logical_and(B==255,A<>255))"`
Note that B is never assigned.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with VRTs. From the [gdalbuildvrt](http://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html) documentation:

> If there is some amount of spatial overlapping between files, the
>   order of files appearing in the list of source matter: files that are
>   listed at the end are the ones from which the content will be fetched.
>   Note that nodata will be taken into account to potentially fetch data
>   from less prioritary datasets, but currently, alpha channel is not
>   taken into account to do alpha compositing (so a source with alpha=0
>   appearing on top of another source will override is content). This
>   might be changed in later versions.

So for your example, your command would be something like:

```
gdalbuildvrt output.vrt rasterA.tif rasterB.tif
```

You may need to do some pre-processing to deal with the nodata.

Once you get the desired result, you can gdal_translate the VRT as necessary.

If needed, you can even control the handling of multiple input resolutions using the -resolution switch (average is the default) in gdalbuildvrt.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this can be done with `gdal_merge` by telling it to ignore the nodata values with the `-n` flag:

`gdal_merge -n -32768 -o out.tif rasterB.tif rasterA.tif`

This will merge rasterA on top of rasterB but not in places where rasterA has nodata pixels (of the value -32768 in this case).

From the [`gdal_merge` documentation](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html):

> -n nodata_value:  Ignore pixels from files being merged in with this pixel value

Comment: I've tried that, this unfortunately doesn't work if your rasters don't fit in memory.

Comment: Ah, the old memory problem. If you are not afraid of Python you could copy the logic from `gdal_merge.py` and use it for a windowed/striped approach - which would solve the issue of fitting the whole dataset into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if `-n [NoDataValue]` does not work for you, try `-n nan`. I had a rasteA with NoDataValue assigned -32768, according to `gdalinfo rasterA` but the tool gdal_merge.py doesn't seem to recognize it. Here is the entire code

`gdal_merge.py -n nan -o outfile.tif rasterB.tif rasterA.tif`