# How to get novalue data of xyz points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, masking, nodata, xyz

I have multibeam and single beam xyz points.

I am looking to do the exact same process as [Patch over raster A with values from raster B where raster A values are nodata in GDAL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175961/patch-over-raster-a-with-values-from-raster-b-where-raster-a-values-are-nodata-i) as I want to infill the single beam NODATA values with values from the multibeam.

I have used Natural Neighbour as seen in pic below to rasterize my data.

I notice that step 1 is to create a nodata mask. How do I find my nodata value that I should be using? In the above example the person knew theirs was 255.

I use ArcGIS for viewing of the data.

[image]